# C++ Lambda capture by reference

Tags: c++, lambda

As far I know, after running the following code myString should have got the value "Inside lambda3.secondLambda". Instead it will still have the value "Initialized".

```
std::string myString("Initialized");
auto lambda3 = [&]() { [&myString]() { myString = "Inside lambda3.secondLambda"; }; };
```

The first lambda captures all variables by reference and the sencond captures only myString by reference. Why does it not behave as I have expected?

Comment: You never actually call those closures. Do you expect them to be executed?

Comment: Ok, it makes perfect sense. So how do I run them in this case?

Comment: Depends what you actually want to do. Do you want calling `lambda3()` to also call the inner closure, or do you want to return it so you can call `lambda3()()`?

Comment: I'm not shure. By the end I want to have the desired value for myString which is "Inside lambda3.secondLambda"

Comment: @CPJ, but lambda is akin to a function. Imagine you have a function foo(), which sets a string. Unless you **call** your foo, nothing is gonna happen!

Comment: @CPJ if that's all you want, then see my answer; you do not need nested lambdas.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By specifying the body of the lambda, you specify code that *would be* called when the lambda's `operator()` is called.

So you need to actually call the lambdas, otherwise it's simply code inside the definition of functions which never get called. You can do:

```
auto lambda3 = [&] {
  auto l = [&myString] {
    myString = "Inside lambda3.secondLambda";
  };
  l();
};
lambda3();
```

To take it one step further, you can return the inner lambda and then execute it like this:

```
auto lambda3 = [&] {
  return [&myString] {
    myString = "Inside lambda3.secondLambda";
  };
};
lambda3()();
```

Comment: So, if i do not return the inner lambda, will not run it (the second lambda)?

Comment: If you just return a lambda that defines a lambda in a local scope, but never uses it, then no, it won't be called. Whenever you define a lambda, its code won't run (aside from initialization in the closure), until you actually run it.

Comment: @CPJ a lambda is like a function definition -- you still must execute it by calling it, it doesn't run on its own. You have two lambdas, so both must be called explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

You have defined a closure, but not actually run the function. You must actually run it like `lambda3()` if you want to execute its body.

However, you have nested lambdas, so you need to run what's in the lambda as well. It's not clear why you are doing this. Your inner lambda is neither assigned inside the outer lambda's scope (so you can run it inside the lambda using the same syntax), or returned (so the caller of this lambda can run what it returns).

If you returned it, you could do `lambda3()()`:

```
auto lambda3 = [&]() { return [&myString]() { myString = "Inside    
     lambda3.secondLambda"; }; };
```

Note: only the word `return` was added to allow `lambda3()()` to work.

In this particular example, you are better served with just:

```
auto lambda3 = [&myString]() { 
      myString = "Inside lambda3.secondLambda"; };
```

Comment: Thanks. This is only a test for a non particular example. I am aware that I could have made modifications to myString inside the outer lambda, but this nonsense of inner lambda is for other scenario.